# Rails way to edit multiple attributes on a model from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model

I have a model `Person` with the following attributes:

`:name, :state, :age, :town`

Let's say I want to be able to edit all of the attributes except for `:name` from that Person's edit view. Is there a "rails" way to do this, and if so what would I write without looping through each attribute and creating a form?

Right now, I've got something like this:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>

    <%= person_form.fields_for :age do |age_form| %>
        <%= age_form.text_field :age %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

And I would do that for each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be just a standard form since the object you're wrapping the form around has all of the attributes.

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>
  <%= f.text_field :town %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, you can add labels and whatever else you need to the form.